# Pass the model value as parameter in html.actionlink Jquery method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I am generating dynamic links using below code in mvc razor views.

```
@foreach (App.Models.Users item in Model )
{
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmp", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "DeleteConfirm()" })
}
```

i want to pass the id or some other filed of model(item.Name) currently clicked link to Jquery method.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmp", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class="emp_delete", title=item.Name })
```

As I can see from tags, you using `jquery`, so you can create any `attributes` and then bind events, also remember about [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for custom attributes.

```
$('.emp_delete').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   alert($this.attr('title'));
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID into your `DeleteConfirm` method:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmp", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "DeleteConfirm(" + item.Id ")" });
```